# Abstraction hindering use of custom types, what are the rules to follow in an implementation?

Tags: c#, implementation, base-class, type-systems

I have built a custom typesystem for usage in C# scripting inside an application. The scripts are compiled on-the-fly and allow interaction with the application internal data. This typesystem is designed in an abstract way using interfaces like `IValue`. Implementation of `IValue` can be a `RefString`, `RefInteger`, `RefDouble` (among many others, but this is sufficient for demonstrating my issue).

Now we come to the point where I get stuck... The use of these `IValue` objects is somewhat unnatural. It is considered as a good design to always use the interfaces to interact with the objects but there is no possibility to define an implicit conversion or overloading an operator for interfaces. This yields to situations where ugly explicit casting is unavoidable so that the right operator gets used.

Example:

```
IValue Add(IValue a, IValue b)
{
    //return a+b; // won't work: which operator +() to use?
    return (RefInteger)a + (RefInteger)b;
}
```

In the case of C# in expressions involving value types, implicit conversions are provided. What is a good way to design such a custom system?

I rewrote the typesystem removing the `IValue` interface and introducing a `RefValue` base class. This way already a part of the explicit casts could be eliminated. I implemented some of the operator overloading in this base class but that caused a lot of trouble with the default conversion operators... Beside this the logic to implement in the operator implementation implicates a lot of knowledge about the types in the system. I think this is somehow still the way that one must go but what are the rules to follow, to implement this in a good and safe way?

**EDIT**: After struggling a while, some of the rules I could find out are:

- Declare implicit only the conversion operators from base-types (int, double, string, ...)
- Declare explicit the conversions to base-types (to avoid implicit casts to int!! what happens quite often, but why?)
- To avoid ambiguous calls the +, -, /, * operators should not be overridden in the base class and in the derived classes. [What is the way to go then? I did the operation overloading in the derived classes, this requires casting on use, which is again ugly...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are supposed to be able to make an `Add` operation on all `IValue`s, perhaps the interface should include an `Add` method? Then you could do `return a.Add(b);`, and push the knowledge of how to perform the operation into each type.

One problem is that as it looks now, you could get calls where `a` is `RefString` and `b` is `RefInteger`, which is probably not what you want. Generics can help fix that:

```
T Add<T>(T a, T b) where T : IValue
{
    return a.Add(b);
}
```

(Of course you would need to add null checking and such as appropriate)

Comment: I still have issues with the default type conversion if I make a `IValue b = 6;` for example. This cannot be declared in the interface and works if I have an implicit conversion operator in the `RefInteger` class. The idea to involve generics can maybe save me from some trouble, thanks for the hint. Operators like +, *, /, - cannot be declared in interfaces, or did I miss something?

Comment: @jdehaan: No, as far as I know there is no way for declaring operators in an interface.

Comment: I turned my design on using a concrete class using some allowed implicit conversions and forcing casts for others in the same fashion as numeric promotion in the ECMA 334 standard. That seems to at least privide good readable code and meet the type conversion requirements. Thanks for your help, I accepted your answer in the end you were right in the sense that there is no optial way of solving it at the interface level.